# Laravel - Can't find an image, though it is there in the disk. Can't reach it even through typing the URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

So I'm building an app in Laravel and it's my first time using the framework by myself without any help aside from the internet, so I'm having quite a bit of trouble in some areas. One of them is that the images I upload seem to be impossible for laravel to find and serve, even though they are getting uploaded to the correct location in the filesystem. I am working on my local environment with Valet. Also, I have already made the symlink between storage and public as instructed by the documentation.

Here's the code that uploads the image:

```
$fileDir = 'public/enterprise/main';
$tempImage = request()->file('main_img');
$newImage = $tempImage->store($fileDir);
```

And here's how I'm trying to call it:

```
<div class="col-xs-8"><img src="{{ asset('storage/app/'.$enterprise->main_img) }}"></div>
```

The url laravel seems to be trying to reach is this:

```
http://vbi.dev/storage/app/public/enterprise/main/MgfjPKWL8DIFgHDrMccOCsOkZZH0QmFAsput07n5.jpeg
```

Finally, my config/filesystems file:

```
<?php
return [
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        'img' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('images')
        ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Where is the file `MgfjPKWL8DIFgHDrMccOCsOkZZH0QmFAsput07n5.jpeg` actually located? Hint, if it's linux, go to your project root and do `find . -name MgfjPKWL8DIFgHDrMccOCsOkZZH0QmFAsput07n5.jpeg`.

Comment: That returned    ./storage/app/public/enterprise/main/MgfjPKWL8DIFgHDrMccOCsOkZZH0QmFAsput07n5.jpeg

Comment: Have you linked your public disk  `php artisan storage:link`  as stated here  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass only the folders where to store the file in the public directory without including the `public`, And you can specify a Disk inthe second argument like this :

```
$fileDir = 'enterprise/main';
$tempImage = request()->file('main_img');
$newImage = $tempImage->store($fileDir, 'public');
```

And the same thing in the view the asset method will automaticly add the path for the public folder for you :

```
<div class="col-xs-8"><img src="{{ asset($enterprise->main_img) }}"></div>
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to also change where I stored the file to use the 'public' disk, like this -> 

    $newImage = $tempImage->store($fileDir, 'public');